# How to scrape a table with multiple headers?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

[image: Table]

I am trying to scrape a table and display it in pycharm, but scraping it gives me "keyerror".

```
import pandas as pd
pd.set_option('display.max_columns', None)
pd.set_option('display.width', None)
pd.set_option('display.max_colwidth', None)

url = pd.read_html("https://azurlane.koumakan.jp/List_of_Large_Cruiser_Guns")

#   User input and lists with table headers
eq_name = input(str())
df = url[1]
table_headers = {'Unnamed: 2': 'Firepower', 'Unnamed: 3': 'Anti-air'}
display_data = ['Equipment', 'Firepower', 'Anti-air', 'Rnd', 'Dmg', 'Coef', 'VT', 'Rld',
            'Surface DPS', 'Rng', 'Sprd', 'Angle', 'Attr', 'Ammo']
df.rename(columns=table_headers, inplace=True)
df.fillna('0', inplace=True)
df.reset_index(drop=True, inplace=True)

#   Large cruisers triple 283mm (sk c/28)
if eq_name == "Triple 283mm (SK C/28)".casefold():
    df = df.loc[[0]]
    name_notes = df[display_data]
    print(name_notes)
```

Comment: aalways put full error message (starting at word "Traceback") in question (not comment) as text (not screenshot, not link to external portal). There are other useful information.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your columns mapper doesn't match the column names, try with

```py
table_headers = {'Unnamed: 2_level_0' : 'Firepower',
                 'Unnamed: 3_level_0' : 'Anti-air',
                 'Unnamed: 2_level_1': 'Firepower',
                 'Unnamed: 3_level_1': 'Anti-air'
                 }
```